# Mysql search with comma delimited string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I have 1 mysql table called **colors** with rows **id** and **name**

```
1 - yellow
2 - black
3 - red
4 - green
5 - white
6 - blue
```

How can I get array of IDs if I have, for example, search string

```
["colors"]=> string(14) "blue,red,white"
```

Comment: Goldie, I hope you read my comment, as you 'accepted' a solution you should not actually use. When your table grows large, that query will grow increasingly slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

```
select id from tab where find_in_set(name, '$colors') > 0
```

NB: as per Dan's comment below, this query doesn't use indexes and will be slow on a large table. A query with IN is better:

```
select id from tab where name IN ('blue', 'red', 'white')
```

Comment: Can this query make use of an index on the name column?

Comment: The answer is no, an index can't be used, so while it's shorter, it's not elegant in the engineering sense of the word. An `=` or `IN` comparison is a better query.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = explode(",", $colors);
$search = implode("', '", $array); // implode instead of impode

$sql = "
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM
  colors
WHERE
  name IN ('$search')
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //do something with the matches
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
$colors = "blue,red,white";

// Exploding string to array
$colors = explode($colors, ',');
$colors_list = array();
foreach($colors as &$color)
{
   // Escaping every element
   $colors_list[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($color)."'";
}

// Executing the query
$query = mysql_query('SELECT `id` FROM `colors` WHERE `name` IN ('.implode(', ', $colors_list).')');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: If you're going to escape the elements, do it with `mysql_real_escape_string`, not your own non-equivalent code.