# MySQL searching from comma separated string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Structure like this table.

```
          ID                           Category            Publisher

           1                             1,2                  A
           2                             1                    B
           3                             2                    C
           4                             1                    D
           5                             2                    E
           6                             2,3,1                F
```

I want a query, when i search for category for 1,3 then it's return
following

I tried but don't get any optimized way.

```
          ID                           Category            Publisher

           1                             1,2                  A
           2                             1                    B
           4                             1                    D
           6                             2,3,1                F
```

Comment: Fix your data structure so you use a junction table.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a "table" not a "string".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql search with comma delimited string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897176/mysql-search-with-comma-delimited-string)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where find_in_set(1, category) > 0
or find_in_set(3, category) > 0
```

But actually you should never store multiple values in a single column. Better change your table design.

Comment: Hey, I don't want to pass single time value (1,3). then please do accordingly

Answer (score 0):

While pure SQL does not offer the tools to compare between two sets, this can be implemented in code (JavaScript/PHP) or using stored procedures.

In order to use pure SQL, you could implement a stored procedure to return the comma-separated string as a single-column temporary table ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218174/3873012) and [this post](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) can give you an idea for implementing this part).

And then, utilizing what you have created, assuming the function is implemented
`STR_SPLIT(<string>, <delimiter>)` and returns a table with a single column named `colName`, you could write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `tblName`.*
FROM `tblName`
INNER JOIN STR_SPLIT('1,3',',') `given`
   ON FIND_IN_SET(`given`.`colName`, `category`) > 0
```

This will take each value and match it separately, which will created duplicates that are going to be eliminated by the `DISTINCT` statement, making this a non-ideal solution.

I'd recommend using a reference table in this case of data, which will have made this issue a breeze to handle, or implementing a partial solution and finishing code-side.

Comment: unable to get you . please provide sql fiddle solution if you can.

Comment: Implement an STR_SPLIT function, then this query will do the trick for you. 
Then again, this is a complicated solution for a simple issue. If you are  still able to introduce schema changes, do it.