# PHP + MySQLi - no idea how to query DB to solve my problem

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursive-query

I've got the following MySQLi-DB:

```
    ╔═════════════╦═══════════╦════════════════╗
    ║ category_id ║ parent_id ║ name           ║
    ╠═════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
    ║ 28          ║ 1         ║ blog root      ║
    ╠═════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
    ║ 30          ║ 28        ║ painting       ║
    ╠═════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
    ║ 31          ║ 30        ║ kids painting  ║
    ╠═════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
    ║ 32          ║ 30        ║ teens painting ║
    ╠═════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
    ║ 35          ║ 28        ║ recipes        ║
    ╠═════════════╬═══════════╬════════════════╣
    ║ 36          ║ 28        ║ diy            ║
    ╚═════════════╩═══════════╩════════════════╝
```

It's category-tree

```
    blog root
        painting
            kids painting
            teens painting
        recipes
        diy
```

I need to create a query which will result all category_id's for a category with all it's subcategories.

EXAMPLE:

```
1) query with category_id = 30 --> result 30, 31, 32
2) query with category_id = 28 --> result 28, 30, 31, 32, 35, 36
3) query with category_id = 35 --> result 35
```

My newbe query is:

```
SELECT `category_id` FROM `blog_category` WHERE `category_id` = 28 OR `parent_id` = 28
```

this will result 28, 30, 35, 36 --> missing 31, 32

How can I solve that problem?

**Edit:
In MySQL not possible as it seems.**

So how can I create with PHP and easy Mysql-queries an comma delimited string to do a final query like
[this solution on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897250/4111020)?

--->

```
... WHERE category_id IN ('$string')
```

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use a recursive query to traverse the hierarchical tree. This feature is available in MySQL 8.0 only:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select category_id, parent_id, name, 1 lvl from mytable where category_id = 28
    union all
    select t.category_id, t.parent_id, t.name, c.lvl + 1
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.parent_id = c.category_id
)
select * from cte order by lvl, category_id
```

This gives you one row per child, ordered by increasing depth, then by `category_id`.

If you want a comma separated value instead of a set of rows, then you can just change the last part of the query to use aggregation:

```
select group_concat(category_id order by lvl, category_id) all_category_ids
from cte
```